# How to merge two lists and update items with duplicate IDs

Tags: c#, .net

```
Class Test 
{ 
   int Id {get;set;}

   String Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have two lists with below ids and values

```
List<Test> list1 = new List<Test>();

list1.Add(new Test() {Id =5,Name=John);

list1.Add(new Test() {Id =2,Name=Jason);

list1.Add(new Test() {Id =8,Name=Jerry);

List<Test> list2 = new List<Test>

list2.Add(new Test() {Id =2,Name=Jack);

list2.Add(new Test() {Id =4,Name=Ron);

list2.Add(new Test() {Id =2,Name=Harry);
```

From the above two lists , I need a single list with All the duplicate ids replaced with unique numbers 
which is based on their current id incremented by 1

```
Id =2,Name=Jason;

Id =3,Name=Harry;

Id =4,Name=Jack;

Id =5,Name=Ron;

Id =6,Name=John;

Id =8,Name=Jerry;
```

Comment: What if incrementing the id by 1 also results in a duplicate?

Comment: And why didn't John keep the id 5?  It wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: In the final list I need unique ids on all the items , hence that 5 was replaced

Comment: So is it ok to just assign new ids to everything?

Comment: Why not just assign new unique IDs to all the elements? It seems simpler and in my eyes you're not really losing anything

Comment: What about the fact that list2 has duplicate ids itself already?  That seems suspiciously not like an "ID".

Comment: What happens if there is an `{ id = 12, name = "flydog" } ` in both lists?

Comment: yes I understand , the whole thing looks suspicious , but that's what I need unfortunately

Comment: It will be replaced with { id = 12, name = "flydog" } and { id = 13, name = "flydog" }

Comment: You are not "merging" then.  You are _concatenating_ and _renumbering_.  `auto merged = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();` then renumber with `int unusedId = 1; merged.ForEach(item => item.Id = unusedId++);`

Comment: There seems to be no logical order applied to the final list in respect to the earlier two. Why are they in that order, or is any order fine, as long as the Ids are unique?

Comment: I think that @Wyck has your solution in his comment.  You might consider having some ordering (say by the initial ID field (even though it's not unique)

Comment: Also, `Id` will very likely need to be at least `internal` (or `public`) to be able to make this change.

Comment: Order doesn't matter , but the final list should have unique IDs and the duplicates should have their ID's replaced with +1

Comment: Tried Wyck solution , it doesn't work :(

Comment: So are you just trying to do this, but more efficiently?  `List<Test> merged = list1.Concat(list2).OrderBy(item => item.Id).ToList(); merged.ForEach(item => { while (merged.Count(x => x.Id == item.Id) > 1) item.Id++; }); merged = merged.OrderBy(item => item.Id).ToList();`

Comment: The answer by Olivier Jacot-Descombes worked for me , but nonetheless will try your solution too , thanks a ton for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would merge the list and sort them by `Id` and `Name` to get a well defined and reproducible order.

```
var list1 = new List<Test> {
    new Test() { Id = 5, Name = "John" },
    new Test() { Id = 2, Name = "Jason" },
    new Test() { Id = 8, Name = "Jerry" }
};

var list2 = new List<Test> {
    new Test() { Id = 2, Name = "Jack" },
    new Test() { Id = 4, Name = "Ron" },
    new Test() { Id = 2, Name = "Harry" }
};

var merged = list1
    .Concat(list2)
    .OrderBy(t => t.Id)
    .ThenBy(t => t.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Now loop through the items in the merged list and detect whether an `Id` is a duplicate by comparing it to the last `Id`. If it is increment it.

```
int lastId = Int32.MinValue;
foreach (Test t in merged) {
    if (t.Id <= lastId) {
        t.Id = lastId + 1;
    }
    lastId = t.Id;
}
```

---

My output

```
foreach (Test t in merged) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{t.Id}  {t.Name}");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

shows:

```
2  Harry
3  Jack
4  Jason
5  Ron
6  John
8  Jerry
```

Comment: I added a test output. I don't see additional elements. The final list contains the 6 elements of  the two lists.

Comment: No. The first element is Harry with an Id of 2. Did you use another setup? I've added my test setup in my answer now. Harry Jack and Jason had the same Id = 2. Therefore they are now sorted alphabetically. The other ones are sorted by their Id.

Comment: It works , sorry my bad , thanks a ton for the answer , will test further with diff combination of data

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test> list1 = new List<Test>() {
                new Test() {Id =5,Name="John"},
                new Test {Id =2,Name="Jason"},
                new Test() {Id =8,Name="Jerry"}
            };
            List<Test> list2 = new List<Test> {
                new Test() {Id =2,Name="Jack"},
                new Test() {Id =4,Name="Ron"},
                new Test() {Id =2,Name="Harry"}
            };

            List<Test> list3 = list1.Concat(list2).GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Test 
    { 
       public int Id {get;set;}

       public String Name {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns only unique elements , I need all the elements

Comment: You expected answer is wrong.  How can you get id's 3 and 6 when they are not in the inputs?

Comment: Yeah that's the renumbered values , as there we some duplicates , duplicates will be incremented by 1 with their current value

Comment: Incrementing by 1 doesn't work when the next higher id is already used.  It is just easier to renumber the entire list.